# Display html with different styles on one page without interference

Tags: css

I'm trying to display several pages (ex.: google.com, yahoo.com ...) on one page. I'm pulling the html of those pages using cURL multi, and then showing all the results on one page for me to see. The problem is that the first page's css messes up all the lower page's css.

Ex.: Yahoo is the first page and has a pretty diverse CSS styling, the next is MSN, which overrides most CSS, but not all of it, and it looks weird.

Any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As much as I hate it, but using iFrames is perhaps the quickest way you can do this.

The better option is the harder one where you would add prefix in your styles or classes in the ones that don't have.

So if the first site defines H1 and then the second site defines H1 differently, you would do H1.firstsite and then H1.secondsite, etc and then in the HTML add class to all H1 tag's.

To be on the safe side, do the similar manipulation to all classes/Ids as well, that way there is no chance of conflict.

PS: Some content may not be shown in an iframe.

Comment: The iframe thingy wouldn't work, I'm using cURL for a purpose, some pages being loaded are password protected which can't be accessed with an iframe. The second idea ... it is hard, I would need to modify both the HTML and all CSS included in each page. That's a heck of a parsing animal that I would need to build for just a more convenient view.

Comment: Do not believe there is another simpler way. How about using a span with an ID for each site and then edit the CSS alone to include that ID before each definition. So for google, you would only change the CSS to include something like #google h1, #google h2, etc and then your container span would have a ID attribute with value google.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this..

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="600px" frameborder="0px"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com" width="600px" frameborder="0px"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.bin.com" width="600px" frameborder="0px"></iframe>
```

Comment: As I sad already in a comment to another post, I can't put them in an iframe since some pages are not accessible through iframe (password protected ...) that's why I use cURL. The only way it would work, I'd have to pull the page's HTML with curl, then in a temp directory create HTML files for each page, and load them with an iframe from my local server then.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using iFrames to load separate pages (or a single page with different query strings) where the content retrieved with cURL. Basically split the cURL operations and access them with iFrames.

That's the simplest and most straight-forward way I see, with least amount of changes to the work you have already done.